# WPF: Why doesn't PageFunction return to calling Window?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, pagefunction

In a WPF Project I am navigating to a `PageFunction` from a `Window` using a `Frame` that is the content of the `Window`. The trouble is the `PageFunction` doesn't return back to the calling `Window`. In fact, calling OnReturn(...) in the `PageFunction` throws an `InvalidOperationException` saying:

> NavigationWindow of PageFunction was already closed or navigated to different content

Why does the exception get thrown?

Here is some sample code that shows the problem:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Frame x:Name="frame" />
```

MainWindow Code Behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var myPageFunction = new MyPageFunction();

        myPageFunction.Return += MyPageFunction_Return;
        frame.Navigate(myPageFunction);

    }

    private void MyPageFunction_Return(object sender, ReturnEventArgs<string> e)
    {
        // Doesn't get here!
    }
}
```

PageFunction.xaml

```
<PageFunction
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
x:Class="WpfApplication3.MyPageFunction"
x:TypeArguments="sys:String"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
Title="MyPageFunction">
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="btnReturn" Click="btnReturn_Click" Content="Return"/>
</Grid></PageFunction>
```

PageFunction code behind:

```
   public partial class MyPageFunction : PageFunction<String>
{
    public MyPageFunction()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnReturn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // THIS THROWS EXCEPTION!
        OnReturn(new ReturnEventArgs<string>("return"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The window should be a NavigationWindow, i.e. you should change the base type of the MainWindow from Window to NavigationWindow, and the Return event can only be handled the calling *page* as documented on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602911%28v=vs.110%29.aspx